# How to run Homebrew service with flags?

Tags: macos, unix, homebrew, plist, macos-sonoma

I'm running on macOS Sonoma and trying to run this service called [AutoRaise](https://github.com/sbmpost/AutoRaise). Someone made a Homebrew package for it [here](https://github.com/Dimentium/homebrew-autoraise). I installed it using Homebrew with my desired flag, `brew install autoraise --with-dexperimental_focus_first`.

My problem is starting the service. These are the flags the service can take:

```
-pollMillis 50 -delay 1 -focusDelay 0 -warpX 0.5 -warpY 0.1 -scale 2.5 -altTaskSwitcher false -ignoreSpaceChanged false -ignoreApps "App1,App2" -stayFocusedBundleIds "Id1,Id2" -disableKey control -mouseDelta 0.1
```

I only want `-delay 0 -focusDelay 1`. I tried to pass it after `brew services start` but got an error saying flags not supported. I also tried modifying the file in `/usr/local/Cellar/autoraise/4.7/homebrew.mxcl.autoraise.plist` but didn't work either.

Here's what I tried in the file.

```
// 1
<string>/usr/local/opt/autoraise/bin/AutoRaise -focusDelay 1 -delay 0</string>

// 2
    <array>
        <string>/usr/local/opt/autoraise/bin/AutoRaise</string>
        <string>-delay 0</string>
        <string>-focusDelay 1</string>
    </array>

// 3
    <array>
        <string>/usr/local/opt/autoraise/bin/AutoRaise</string>
        <string>-delay=0</string>
        <string>-focusDelay=1</string>
    </array>

// 4
    <array>
        <string>/usr/local/opt/autoraise/bin/AutoRaise</string>
        <string>--delay=0</string>
        <string>--focusDelay=1</string>
    </array>
```

Can someone please help me out?

Comment: `-delay` and `0` are separate arguments, so they need to be in separate `<string>`s. Same with `-focusDelay` and `1`.

Comment: That worked! You want to type it out so I can select it as an answer? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `-delay` and `0` are a single logical item (so to speak), they're actually separate arguments to `AutoRaise`, so they need to be in separate `<string>`s. The same goes for `-focusDelay` and `1`. Therefore, you need to use this:

```
<array>
    <string>/usr/local/opt/autoraise/bin/AutoRaise</string>
    <string>-delay</string>
    <string>0</string>
    <string>-focusDelay</string>
    <string>1</string>
</array>
```